# "Checking for new Ubuntu release... no new release found" when I run "do-release-upgrade"

Tags: do-release-upgrade

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sudo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 do-release-upgrade 
新しい Ubuntu のリリースをチェックしています [translation: checking for new Ubuntu release]
新しくリリースされたものはありません [translation: no new release found]
```

Question 1: Why doesn't `sudo do-release-upgrade` propose upgrading to 16.04? I get the same message if I use the `-d` or `-r` flag.

Question 2: Why is the `LANG` envar ignored? I'd prefer to do the upgrade in English instead of Japanese as it's easier for me to read.

Comment: Reviewers: I don't agree that this is a problem that cannot be reproduced. Although [the OP's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018089/22949) would benefit from more details, it will likely be sufficient to help others who have this same problem and find this question by searching.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. It turned out that there was a setting in update-manager to not propose any OS version upgrades, and then do-release-upgrade wouldn't find any new versions. After changing the settings, do-release-upgrade found Ubuntu 16.04.